# Which side of cell was clicked

Tags: jquery

I have a table 'grid' with multiple rows, say 50, and multiple columns, say 50 that are both around 20px square. The user can click and change the cell bg color, which is relevant because I think it needs to stay a table. I would like to let the user 'draw' lines along the grid. Would it be possible to detect which side of the cell they clicked or clicked closest to? So I can set that border to x pixels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the document-relative mouse coordinates through the [pageX](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageX/) and [pageY](http://api.jquery.com/event.pageY/) properties of the `event` object.

From there, you can subtract the element's [offset()](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) to get element-relative coordinates. Then you only need to compare the resulting horizontal coordinate with half the element's [width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/):

```
$("td").click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (e.pageX - $this.offset().left > $this.width() / 2) {
        // Clicked on the right side.
    } else {
        // Clicked on the left side.
    }
});
```

Comment: exactly..I can't believe it was that simple. Just amazing. Thank you.

Comment: Elegant solution! I wonder, how could I detect clicking the middle of the cell?

Comment: @Cory, you could test if `e.pageX - $this.offset().left == $this.width() / 2`. This looks like a usability nightmare, though. Requiring pixel-perfect clicks from the user is usually not a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

It is a simple matter of capturing the x and y coordinates of the mouse pointer and doing some simple math. E.g.:

```
$("td").mousemove(function(e) {
    var xpos = e.pageX;
    var ypos = e.pageY;
    console.log(xpos + " " + ypos);
    if(xpos < $(this).width() / 2) {
        console.log("somewhere left");    
    } else {
        console.log("somewhere right");   
    }
});
```

[**Demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/MsEMA/1/)

Comment: `event.pageX` and `event.pageY` are document-relative. You would have to translate them into element-relative coordinates for your code to give meaningful results.

Comment: Awesome...just a bit of math to apply to my page. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aMouse_Position). This example provides absolute coordinates. You'll have to adapt to your case by doing some calculations to determine which area of which cell was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this like that:

1. find the mouse position (of the window)
2. find the mouse position related to clicked cell